How do I instruct Azure Monitor to select Role Instance based on container name?
I'm currently migration from Application Insights Telemetry to AzureMonitor and OtlpExporter and discovered that Role Instance no longer matches the name given by Helm chart. Instead it seem to get a random generated GUID. I've tried to turn off automatic generation when creating the resource but it doesn't change the behavior.
services
  .AddOpenTelemetry()
  .UseAzureMonitor()
  .WithTracing(trace => {})
  .WithMetrics(metric => {});

I've also turned on RedisInstrumentation and that has the side effect of spamming with verbose logs and I can't find how to turn them of. The SourceContext (from Serilog naming) can't be found in the properties and I use Serilog as logger.
I've tried adding it using builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry() and use the OpenTelemetry Sink for Serilog.

The Rolle Instance was solved by down grading from beta to stable. I’ll update answer with package versions when time allows.
Redis verbose logs is still an issue though.
